# In Openacc, warning: Accelerator restriction: induction variable live-out from loop: i

Tags: c++, openacc

May I know how to use the variable i in the first loop as the addend in the second loop? And moreover, I want to ask if I should use update and whether I should use present($var) to tell compiler the i is already in device.

```
  #include<iostream>

  #include<openacc.h>

  #define N 10

  using namespace std;
  int main(){

    int a[N];

    int i=0;

    #pragma acc data copyin(N) copy(a[:N],i)
 {
    
    #pragma acc parallel loop present(i)

    for(;i<N;i++){
         
            a[i]=i;
        }

        #pragma acc parallel loop //data reduction(a[0:N])
 
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        
            a[j]=j+**i**;//here I would like here i=10 as addend 

    }

 }

  cout<<"a[N]"<<a[N-1]<<endl;


}
```

The result is :
`main:
13, Generating copy(i,a[:]) [if not already present]
21, Generating present(i)
Generating NVIDIA GPU code
21, #pragma acc loop seq
23, Accelerator restriction: induction variable live-out from loop: i
24, Accelerator restriction: induction variable live-out from loop: i
Generating NVIDIA GPU code
26, #pragma acc loop gang /* blockIdx.x */

$ ./teste

a[N]9

i 10

But if I changed the directive

```
#pragma acc data copyin(N) copy(a[:N],i)
{
  


   // int a[N];

   #pragma acc kernels
   {
   // #pragma acc parallel loop
    for(;i<N;i++){
         
            a[i]=i;
        }
  // #pragma acc parallel loop present(i)//data reduction(a[0:N])
        for(int j=0;j<N;j++){
        a[j]=j+i;

    }
   }
}
```

I got the result :

$ ./teste

a[N]19

i 10

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Why not just use `N` instead? Presumably the value of `i` isn't well defined as it's value is different on each thread

Comment: Thanks , I forgot to change the value of index.

Answer (score 1):

Scalars are firstprivate by default, so in the second compute region, you need to add "present(i)" to have the global device copy be used.

Though as Alan commented, taking the last value of i from the first loop seems unnecessary given it's equal to N.  Also, the first loop can't be run in parallel given to get the last value, all previous iterations of the loop must be run in order, thus causing a dependency.

The second example works because both loops are within the same compute region and the compiler is scheduling them to run serially.

Comment: Hello Mat, thanks very much for your suggestion. I understand the meaning of the region and the scope of variables. Your help is always valuable.I added present() and it works well.